# Error Passing SVG React Components as Props (similar posts did not provide fulfilling answers)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, components

I am trying to pass some svg icons my NavItem props, but am running into errors in my developer tools.

This is the error:

[image]

I also narrowed it down to an error when rendering my NavItems, but I really don't know the right way to pass svg icons as props and render them in react. Here is my relevant app.js

**App.js**

```
import './index.css';
import { ReactComponent as BellIcon } from './icons/bell.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MessengerIcon } from './icons/messenger.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CaretIcon } from './icons/caret.svg';
import { ReactComponent as PlusIcon } from './icons/plus.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CogIcon } from './icons/cog.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronIcon } from './icons/chevron.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ArrowIcon } from './icons/arrow.svg';
import { ReactComponent as BoltIcon } from './icons/bolt.svg';
import DataFetching from "../DataFetching";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

/*declare module "*.svg" {
  import { ReactElement, SVGProps } from "react";
  const content: (props: SVGProps<SVGElement>) => ReactElement;
  export default content;
}
*/
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataFetching />
      <Navbar>
        <NavItem icon={<PlusIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<BellIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<MessengerIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<CaretIcon />}>
          <DropdownMenu></DropdownMenu>
        </NavItem>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}


function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">{props.children}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

type TProps ={
  mainText: {
    mainText: String;
    items?: JSX.Element{};
    Icon?:
  }
}
function NavItem(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a href="#" className="icon-button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {props.icon}
      </a>

      {open && props.children}
    </li>
  );
}
```

**arrow.svg**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 448 512">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M257.5 445.1l-22.2 22.2c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L7 273c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L201.4 44.7c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.2 22.2c9.5 9.5 9.3 25-.4 34.3L136.6 216H424c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v32c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H136.6l120.5 114.8c9.8 9.3 10 24.8.4 34.3z" class=""/>
</svg>
```

Does anyone know the correct way to pass these svg components as props so that I don't run into this error? Thanks, please let me know.

Comment: Are you exporting the <svg> from arrow.svg?

Comment: Try <NavItem icon= { ( <PlusIcon /> ) } /> ... I think parentheses ( ) are missing here